# how to host wcf service server ( that run on iis ) on windows service?

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis

I hold part of the wcf application that i using iis as the host.

I want to make this wcf application to run also as a service ( and not only as web service server ) and force my application to do some reading from the disk every 10 second.

But when i using the iis as the host - the wcf application is only do action as response to some web service call and there is no way ( as far as i know ) to run on my application on this case a timer that will do some action every 10 seconds.

But on other side - i want to continue to use the iis (to use the iis default web site) as the host and not make some 'self host' application

Is it possible ?
How to do it ?

Comment: You've already asked what appears to be the same question and accepted the answer...why is this question different than your last one?

Comment: this is not the same question